# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". javascript & electron

Tags: javascript, fs

estoy haciendo una aplicacion con electron, pero mi render.js no puede importar "fs" para guardar un archivo

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

este es mi codigo:

```
import { fs } from 'fs';

console.log("Espera!")
console.log("si alguien te ha dicho que pongas algo en la consola")
console.log("¡No lo hagas!")
console.log("seguramente sea un scam")
console.log("hacerlo puede comprometer la seguridad de tu PC")
    

submit_btn = document.getElementById("submit_btn")

submit_btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("input").value)
    console.log("enviando....")
    fs.writeFile('message.txt', document.getElementById("input").value, 'utf8', callback);
});
```

si quieren toda la estructura de mi app vayan a https://github.com/ticua07/ErrorStackOverflow ahi puse el codigo menos el node_modules porque no me deja :(

Comment: El node modules no debe subierse nunca a un repositorio de versiones, es normal que no te deje, se genera automáticamente

Comment: Que? podrias dar mas detalles sobre tu respuesta

Comment: No es una respuesta, sólo comentaba que es normal que GitHub no te permita subir la carpeta node_modules. Dicha carpeta no se debe añadir como código.

Comment: aaaah si me di cuenta xd

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en tu import.

Para importar `fs` usando la sintaxis de javascript moderno deberías usar

`ìmport * as fs from 'fs'`

Por otro lado si usaras notación de módulos sería

`const fs = require('fs')`

Comment: Curiosamente no puedo encontrar una sola mención a los módulos ES6 en toda la documentación de Electron, todos los ejemplos usan `require`

Comment: ninguna de las 2 soluciones que pusiste funcionaron

Comment: interesante, espérame a revisar tu repo pues ni lo chequié al responderte.

Comment: tienes un módulo `fs` descargado del registro de npm, siendo que `fs` es nativo para node.js. Intenta quitando ese modulo de tu package.json, haciendo una reinstalación y avísame como te va

Comment: [Esto te debería servir también](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994441/how-to-use-fs-module-inside-electron-atom-webpack-application) no trabajo con electron asi que no creo pueda ayudarte mucho mas